# Copy Cell (within a column) if Column Contains Text

Tags: excel-formula

Looking for an excel formula to execute below:

```
      Column 1    Column 2   Column 3
Row1  "Apple"     "Fruit"    "X/Y"
Row2  "Banana"    "Fruit"    "A/B"
```

Copy data from column 3 (different sheet - "Source") if:

1) Column 2 = "Fruit", AND

2) Column 1 = "Apple"

It should return: "X/Y"

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C2:C99, MATCH(1, (Sheet1!B2:B99="Fruit")*(Sheet1!A2:A99="Apple"), 0))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: What, no AGGREGATE?

Comment: @ScottCraner not when you're around ;)

Comment: it returned an error.. does it need an IF condition?

Comment: @mon It's an **array formula** (aka CSE). When entering or editing it, press 
`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Comment: @A.S.H what if I want to add a comparison between times. So, let's say there are 2 rows for Apple and there will be a col. D with 21:00:00 and 22:00 respectively. How can I add the condition that it should get the MIN value from Col. D., so it should return 21:00:00?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the cell where you want your answer. Obviously the references (row1col1) should be replaced with actual cell references.

```
=IF(AND(row1col2="fruit", row1col1="apple"), row1col3, "")
```

Comment: this is the initial formula I used and it's not working. to clarify, if it contains both text or values in those 2 columns (in another sheet), I want to copy the value in the same row under column c.